# Document Set - Restored from Recycle Bin doesn't appear in the document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, restore, recycle-bin

I have strange problem and I can't seem to find an answer/solution.

I have a document library with the **document set content type** enabled with some **site columns**.  Recently some files/document sets were deleted from the library (through OneDrive sync) and when I restored the files/folders from the recycle bin, it is not appearing back in the document library?

When I search for the folder restored, I can find the them in the search results.

When I sync the library back to my machine I can see all the folders (included the restored ones) but can't see them in the library.

Anyone knows what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can still find them because your search engine still has them cached; but once they have been deleted from OneDrive, they are gone. This is one of the issues with OneDrive Sync. Or to be more accurate: the problem when you give end-users this option, without them fully understanding how it operates.

Comment: That's not true.  When you delete the files even if it is through sync it goes into recycle bin and I was able to recover those files from bin.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I delete a document set from OneDrive sync client, and restore it from site collection recycle bin in SharePoint Online, the document set restores to the library.

From your description, the document set seems in the library but you can not view it.

Try to clear the browser cache to check if the issue exists.

To narrow down the issue, you can test in other sites/libraries check if you can reproduce the issue.

And delete the document sets from library in SharePoint UI, restore them from recycle bin, check if the issue exists.